# Foreign key for multiple columns of one table referenced to the same primary key?

Tags: database, foreign-keys, relational-database, foreign-key-relationship

I am currently creating a database using SQL but I have found the need to use a foreign key to in 3 different fields in a single table.

I have CourseID1, CourseID2 and CourseID3 in students courses table. Each of those 3 fields need to be foreign and reference to the CourseID field in the course table which is a primary key.

Is this possible? how do I go about doing this?

Thank you

Comment: of course it is possible. But i don't see any purpose in doing so. 
what are you trying to achieve doing it.?

Answer (score 0):

This is possible.  You would do:

```
foreign key (CourseId1) references Courses(CourseId),
foreign key (CourseId2) references Courses(CourseId),
foreign key (CourseId3) references Courses(CourseId),
```

That said, you don't want to do this.  Having multiple columns with numeric appendages usually means that you want an association/junction table.  In this case, you want a table named something like `StudentCourses` which would have one row per student and per course that the student takes.